# 'ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri)' is obsolete: Use HttpClient instead

Tags: httpclient, c#-6.0, servicepointmanager

Started getting this error after updating  C# upgraded from NET 5 to 6-

Warning SYSLIB0014 'ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri)' is obsolete: 'WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.'

```
var servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(requestUri.GetEndpoint());
            if (servicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout == -1){}
```

Answer (score 3):

On the [Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0#networking) of the [Breaking changes in .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0) there's [WebRequest, WebClient, and ServicePoint are obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated):

> ## WebRequest, WebClient, and ServicePoint are obsolete
>
> xref:System.Net.WebRequest, xref:System.Net.WebClient, and xref:System.Net.ServicePoint classes are marked as obsolete and generate a `SYSLIB0014` warning at compile time.
>
> ### Version introduced
>
> 6.0
>
> ### Change description
>
> WebRequest, WebClient, and ServicePoint classes were added to .NET Core in version 2.0 for backward compatibility. However, they introduced several runtime breaking changes, for example, `WebRequest.GetRequestStream` allocates memory for the whole response, and `WebClient.CancelAsync` doesn't always cancel immediately.
>
> Starting in .NET 6, the WebRequest, WebClient, and ServicePoint classes are deprecated. The classes are still available, but they're not recommended for new development. To reduce the number of analyzer warnings, only construction methods are decorated with the ObsoleteAttribute attribute.
>
> ### Recommended action
>
> Use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class instead.
>
> For FTP, since HttpClient doesn't support it, we recommend using a third-party library.
>
> ### Affected APIs
>
> - WebRequest
> - HttpWebRequest
> - FtpWebRequest
> - WebClient
> - ServicePoint

Comment: It just says to use the HttpClient class instead, but nothing more than that. What else needs to happen?

Comment: @NovaDev for what?

Comment: They say use the HttpClient, but they don't say how exactly. For example, there was something like this before: servicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false; 
What is the alternative to that in HttpClient?

Comment: What changed from 5.0 to 6.0? The source code for all versions is available at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/. You just need to select the tag you want.

Comment: @Max Did you ever find the answer to that? I have the exact same questions as you had here.

Answer (score 0):

We can replace `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint` with `SocketsHttpHandler` as this example:

In .NET Framework

```
httpClient = new HttpClient();
ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(_baseAddress)).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
```

In .NET Core

```
        var socketsHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
        {
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        };

        httpClient = new HttpClient(socketsHttpHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress)
        };
```

In detail, you can take a look at this article: https://makolyte.com/csharp-configuring-how-long-an-httpclient-connection-will-stay-open/