# ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint is obsolete in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, migration, .net-6.0, servicepointmanager

Starting in .Net6, ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint is [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.findservicepoint?view=net-7.0) and should not be used.

However, I am using this ServicePoint to log some metadata about my service during a failing case

```
var servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(request.RequestUri);
LogWarning(
    $"active connections = {servicePoint.CurrentConnections}/{servicePoint.ConnectionLimit}, " +
    $"supports pipelining = {servicePoint.SupportsPipelining}, " +
    $"receive buffer size = {servicePoint.ReceiveBufferSize}, " +
    $"idle since = {servicePoint.IdleSince}, " +
    $"max idle time = {servicePoint.MaxIdleTime}, ");
```

However the only recommended guidance is `Use HttpClient instead` without any details on how. Is there any known way to retrieve these properties via the HttpClient?

I found [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872893/servicepointmanager-findservicepointuri-is-obsolete-use-httpclient-instead#:%7E:text=We%20can%20replace%20ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint%20with%20SocketsHttpHandler%20as%20this,%3D%205%20%2A%2060%20%2A%201000%3B%20In.NET%20Core) post that uses socketsHttpHandler instead to modify the connection lifetime but this isn't really what a want. I'm looking more to try and get these values as a 'read' operation.

I tried to find a .Net6 alternative to getting these values but couldn't.

Comment: From [HttpClient example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0#examples) we can know how to use HttpClient, and get responseBody  by `string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` . Could you share your code about  these values in request.RequestUri ?